# Java Simple Recursive Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Here is a simple recursion question in java. This one I have been working on but need to refine my approach.

Write a recursive method with two int parameters, m and n. The precondition requires 0 <= m and m <= n. The method prints a line of m asterisks, then a line of m+1 asterisks, and so on up to a line of n asterisks. Then the same pattern is repeated backward: a line of n asterisks, then n-1, and so on down to n. The only loop allowed in your implementation is a loop to print a line of m asterisks.

This is what I have so far as test methods

```
package Recursion;

class Asterisk 
{
     public static void asterisk(int m, int n) 
     {
        if (m == n) 
        {
           printAsterisk(n);
           return;
        } 
        else if (m < n) 
        {
            printAsterisk(m);
            asterisk(m + 1, n);
        } 
        else 
        {
            printAsterisk(m);
            asterisk(m - 1, m);
        }
     }

    public static void printAsterisk(int m) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
        {
           System.out.print("*");
        }
            System.out.println("");
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       int m = 3;
       int n = 5;

       asterisk(m, n);
   }
}
```

Think of it this way: printAsterisk(6, 5) prints nothing. printAsterisk(3, 5) prints 3 asterisks, then inserts printAsterisk(4, 5), then prints 3 asterisks again.

Expected Output

```
printAsterisk(3, 5)
***
****
*****
*****
****
***
```

My Current Output

```
printAsterisk(3, 5)
***
****
*****
```

Comment: `How should I print using only one method call in main?`  You only have one method call in main() now (and you also have two variable declarations).

Comment: `The precondition requires 0 <= m and m <= n` If this is always true, you can get rid of the else case that handles m > n.  However, for real-life code I would leave it in (consumers of your code are unlikely to remember that precondition years down the road).

Comment: pardon me for earlier, I meant to imply one method call to print the asterisks in sequence desired.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Give an example, your question currently doesn't make any sense.

Comment: So the algorithm should be as follows: printAsterisk(6, 5) prints nothing. printAsterisk(3, 5) prints 3 asterisks, then inserts printAsterisk(4, 5), then prints 3 asterisks again.

Comment: So what's wrong with your method? For an effective question you need to show what your output is compared to what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much simpler.

```
public static void asterisk(int m, int n) {
    printAsterisk(m);
    if (m < n) {
        asterisk(m + 1, n);
    }
    printAsterisk(m);
}
```

Just print `m` asterisk at the begin and the end of the function. And only if m is less than `n` recurse with `m + 1`.

In case of preventing two printed lines if `m > n` do this:

```
public static void asterisk(int m, int n) {
    if (m <= n) {
        printAsterisk(m);
        asterisk(m + 1, n);
        printAsterisk(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: This still prints 2 lines of asterisks even if `m > n`, you should add a catch for that.

Comment: I added the case for `m > n`.

Comment: How is this decrementing? It works fine but I don't understand how

Comment: @FarhanIshraq It isn't decrementing, but because you are printing the next amount of asterisks between 2 lines of the current amount it gives that effect. Try choosing 2 numbers (`m` and `n`) and going through the method step by step yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution, is better the way you have it. Why you want it only with 1 method?

```
package Recursion;

class Asterisk 
{
     public static void asterisk(int m, int n) 
     {
        if (m == n) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
           System.out.print("*");
        }
            System.out.println("");
        } 
        else if (m < n) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
        {
           System.out.print("*");
        }
            System.out.println("");

            asterisk(m + 1, n);
        } 
        else 
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
        {
           System.out.print("*");
        }
            System.out.println("");
            asterisk(m - 1, m);
        }
     }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       int m = 3;
       int n = 5;

       asterisk(m, n);
   }
```

Comment: You can modify the existing code provided. Doesn't have to be one method. I need to call method only once from main.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is kind of messy. You have a return statement inside your first method which is void, so it will certainly not run. 
But the probkem is that you shouldn't have used a void method in the first place , because you need a return statement to make it work recursively, instead of calling it from inside itself.(write return asterisk(m+1,n) inside the 'else if' statement and return asterisk(m-1,n) inside the 'else'). 
Then,writing asterisk(m,n) on main should do the trick.
Sorry for any grammatical issues, I'm writing on a tablet

Comment: so like this right? if (m == n) 
        {
           printAsterisk(n);
           return n;
        } 
        else if (m < n) 
        {
            return asterisk(m + 1, n);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return asterisk(m - 1, m);
        }